# Any function to morph to very similar mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have two meshes by different authors for one particular character of video game. Those are pretty same shape but different number of vertices/faces.

My attempt is trying to reshape A.mech as same as B.mesh, much closer to another one while keep number of vertices/faces.

Attached image is displaying A.mesh and B.mesh same time.

[image]
[image]

All I know is proportional edit/scaling/moving. Is there any other ways to morph to reference mesh(with different number of vertices/faces)?

Thanks for your thoughts and advices!

Comment: Use a shrinkwrap modifier on the mesh to be modified targeting the other one.

Comment: Thx! It works perfectly!!!